# Python Code Creation

Tags: python

I've been trying to make a simple replacement code where a = e, b = z, and so forth. This is what I have so far:

```
done = False 
while not done: 

    Letter = input("Letter:")

    if Letter == "a":
        print("e")

    if Letter == "e":
        print("a")

    if Letter == "b":
        print("z")

    if Letter == "z":
        print("b")

    if Letter == "c":
        print("x")

    if Letter == "x":
        print("c")

    if Letter == "d":
        print("w")

    if Letter == "w":
        print("d")

    if Letter == "f":
        print("v")

    if Letter == "v":
        print("f")

    input = input("Start over? Y/N :") 
    if input == "N": 
        done = True
```

I am able to convert a single letter at a time, but when I input a word, it doesn't convert the whole word to the specially coded message.

Comment: Two comments: (1) it is not clear what you are trying to accomplish, and (2) you have not clearly described the problem that you are facing.  Why can't you type more than a single letter?

Comment: What you have so far is insane; it will take you ages to type all that out. Read [the python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/), focussing on dictionaries and strings. And if you want to ask questions here, read [the help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: Drop an eye on this : http://www.diveintopython.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, try using a dict() to store the mappings. Lots easier.

```
mymappings = dict()

def add_mapping( l1, l2): 
    mymappings[l1] = l2
    mymappings[l2] = l1

add_mapping('a','e')
add_mapping('b','z')
...

word = None
while word != '':
    word = raw_input("Word:")
    print ''.join( [mymappings[x] for x in word if mymappings.has_key(x)] )
```

Then just do a list comprehension on your string to write out the mapped characters. You are not getting 1 letter at a time, you are getting 1 string at a time.  Therefore you need to now write out the string modified.

Also use raw_input, not input for pulling in strings.

Comment: My main problem is for example if I type "aaa" into the program, why don't I get "eee" back?

Comment: Try to understand the concepts used.  First is the usage of a `dict()` data type for storing mappings. Second is the use of a `function` to make populating the dict() easier. Third is using `list comprehension` to process the string through the mapping, return a list of 'converted' characters, Fourth is using `''.join()` to bring that list back into a single string.